# git-user - Working on a shared local repository with multiple users made easier

Tags: python, python-3.x, console, git

I have recently been in a situation where multiple developers worked on a shared local git repository under the same Linux user¹. As one can imagine, it can easily become a bit annoying not to commit changes as someone else if you don't check the values of `git config user.name` and `git config user.email` carefully and then change them accordingly. The same problem might also arise if you happen to work on several projects on your local machine side-by-side where you have to use different "identities", e.g. some work-related and private projects. I decided to tackle this with a little "git extension" that allows you to view and change the committer identity with less of a hassle.

Enter `git user`. To get an idea of its intended use, have a look at the output of `git user -h`:

```
git-user - Helps you to manage multiple users in a shared local repository

Subcommands
-----------
add, update, show, delete

Use git user <subcommand> --help to get more help

Examples
--------
# Add two test users
> git user add itsme "My Last" my.last@domain.tld --credential-username itsme
> git user add itsyou "Your Last" your.last@domain.tld

# activate the first user
> git user itsme
My Last <my.last@domain.tld>
# you can check this yourself with git config.name and git config user.email

# activate the second user
> git user itsyou
Your Last <your.last@domain.tld>

# use git user with no arguments to check which values are currently set
> git user
Your Last <your.last@domain.tld>

> git user show
    itsme: My Last <my.last@domain.tld> (push as 'itsme')
    itsyou: Your Last <your.last@domain.tld>
> git user delete itsyou --force
> git user show
    itsme: My Last <my.last@domain.tld>
```

The code that makes this possible is as follows:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
... omitted for brevity, see help text in question ...
"""
import argparse
import json
import os
import sys
from collections import defaultdict
from subprocess import check_output, CalledProcessError, DEVNULL

DESCRIPTION = sys.modules[__name__].__doc__

__version__ = "0.2.0"


class UserbaseError(Exception):
    """Base class for userbase related exceptions"""


class UserDoesNotExist(UserbaseError):
    """Custom exception to indicate that a user does not exist"""


class UserDoesAlreadyExist(UserbaseError):
    """Custom exception to indicate that a user does already exist"""


class Userbase:
    """Abstraction of the underlying user storage file"""

    DATA_KEYS = ("name", "email", "credential_username")

    def __init__(self, users_file):
        self._users_file = users_file
        self._users = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(str))
        self._load()

    def _load(self):
        if not os.path.isfile(self._users_file):
            print("Creating default at '{}'.".format(self._users_file))
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(self._users_file))
            self.save()

        with open(self._users_file, "r") as json_file:
            self._users.update(json.load(json_file))

    def save(self):
        """Dump the current userbase to file"""
        with open(self._users_file, "w") as json_file:
            json.dump(self._users, json_file)

    def is_known(self, alias):
        """Check if an alias is part of the userbase"""
        return alias in self._users

    def get(self, alias):
        """Try to get user data for an alias

        Parameters
        ----------
        alias: str
            access the data stored under this alias

        Returns
        -------
        dict
            the data associated with the alias. Keys are listed in
            Userbase.DATA_KEYS

        Raises
        ------
        UserDoesNotExist
            If the user is not part of the userbase
        """
        if self.is_known(alias):
            return self._users[alias]

        raise UserDoesNotExist(
            "User with alias '{}' unknown".format(alias)
        )

    def as_dict(self):
        """Access the userbase as a dict"""
        return dict(self._users)

    def update(self, alias, **kwargs):
        """Update the data stored under an alias

        This function does not check whether the user exists or not. If it
        exists, its data will simply be overwritten.

        Parameters
        ----------
        alias: str
            update the data found under this alias
        kwargs: dict
            the script will look for the keys from Userbase.DATA_KEYS in the
            kwargs in order to update the internal database
        """
        for key in Userbase.DATA_KEYS:
            new_value = kwargs[key]
            if new_value is not None:
                self._users[alias][key] = new_value

    def delete(self, alias):
        """Delete a user from the userbase given its alias

        Parameters
        ----------
        alias: str
            the alias to look for

        Raises
        ------
        UserDoesNotExist
            you can probably guess when this is raised
        """
        try:
            del self._users[alias]
        except KeyError:
            raise UserDoesNotExist(
                "User with alias '{}' unknown".format(alias)
            )


try:
    _USERS_FILE = os.environ["GITUSER_CONFIG"]
except KeyError:
    _USERS_FILE = os.path.join(
        os.path.expanduser("~"), ".config", "git-user", "users.json"
    )
_USERS_FILE = os.path.abspath(_USERS_FILE)
_USERS = Userbase(_USERS_FILE)


def add(args):
    """Add a user to the userbase"""
    if _USERS.is_known(args.alias):
        raise UserDoesAlreadyExist(
            "User with alias '{}' already exist. ".format(args.alias)
            + "Delete first or use 'update'"
        )
    kwargs = {name: getattr(args, name, "") for name in Userbase.DATA_KEYS}
    _USERS.update(args.alias, **kwargs)


def update(args):
    """Interactive wrapper around Userbase.update"""
    if not _USERS.is_known(args.alias):
        raise UserDoesAlreadyExist(
            "User with alias '{}' does not exist. ".format(args.alias)
            + "Add first using 'add'"
        )
    kwargs = {name: getattr(args, name, "") for name in Userbase.DATA_KEYS}
    _USERS.update(args.alias, **kwargs)


def delete(args):
    """Interactivate wrapper around Userbase.delete"""
    if _USERS.is_known(args.alias) and not args.force:
        while True:
            answer = input(
                "Really delete user '{}'? [N/y] ".format(args.alias)
            )
            answer = answer.lower().strip()
            if answer in ("yes", "y"):
                break
            if answer in ("no", "n", ""):
                return
    _USERS.delete(args.alias)


def show(args):
    """Show the data of one or all the users in the userbase"""
    to_show = tuple(sorted(_USERS.as_dict().keys()))
    if args.alias is not None:
        to_show = (args.alias, )

    if to_show:
        for alias in to_show:
            cfg = _USERS.get(alias)
            msg = "    {}: {name} <{email}>".format(alias, **cfg)
            if "credential_username" in cfg.keys():
                msg += " (push as '{credential_username}')".format(**cfg)
            print(msg)
    else:
        print("No known aliases.")


def switch(args):
    """Switch to an other user from the userbase and/or show current config

    Set args.quiet to True to avoid seeing the current config as console output
    """
    if args.alias is not None:
        cfg = _USERS.get(args.alias)
        _git_config_name(cfg["name"])
        _git_config_email(cfg["email"])
        credential_username = cfg.get("credential_username", "")
        try:
            _git_config_credential_username(credential_username)
        except CalledProcessError as ex:
            if credential_username not in ("", None):
                raise ex
    if not args.quiet:
        _show_git_config()


def _show_git_config():
    try:
        git_name = _git_config_name().strip().decode("utf8")
        git_email = _git_config_email().strip().decode("utf8")
    except CalledProcessError:
        print(
            "Currently there is no (default) user for this repository.\n"
            "Select one using git user <alias> or manually with git config"
        )
        return
    try:
        git_cred_username = _git_config_credential_username().strip().decode("utf8")
        print("{} <{}> (push as '{}')".format(git_name, git_email, git_cred_username))
        return
    except CalledProcessError:
        # git config has a non-zero exit status if no value is set
        pass

    print("{} <{}>".format(git_name, git_email))


def _git_config_name(name=None):
    args = ["git", "config", "user.name"]
    if name is not None:
        args.append(str(name))
    return check_output(args)


def _git_config_email(email=None):
    args = ["git", "config", "user.email"]
    if email is not None:
        args.append(str(email))
    return check_output(args)


def _git_config_credential_username(username=None):
    # remote_url = _git_get_remote_url(remote).strip().decode("utf8")
    args = ["git", "config"]
    if username == "":
        args.extend(["--remove-section", "credential"])
    else:
        args.append("credential.username")
        if username is not None:
            args.append(username)
    return check_output(args, stderr=DEVNULL)


def main():
    """CLI of the git user helper"""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description=DESCRIPTION, formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)

    # click might be an alternative here, but I want this to be as lightweight
    # as possible
    try:
        command = sys.argv[1]
    except IndexError:
        command = "switch"

    if command in ("add", "update", "delete", "show"):
        subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

        add_subparser = subparsers.add_parser(
            "add", description="Add name and email for an alias")
        add_subparser.add_argument(
            "alias", help="Alias used to access this user's name and email")
        add_subparser.add_argument(
            "name", help="This value gets passed to git config user.name",
            default="")
        add_subparser.add_argument(
            "email", help="This value gets passed to git config user.email",
            default="")
        add_subparser.add_argument(
            "--credential-username",
            help="optional: push credential username",
            default="")
        add_subparser.set_defaults(command=add)

        update_subparser = subparsers.add_parser(
            "update", description="Update an alias")
        update_subparser.add_argument(
            "alias", help="Alias used to access this user's name and email")
        update_subparser.add_argument(
            "--name", help="This value gets passed to git config user.name",
            default=None)
        update_subparser.add_argument(
            "--email", help="This value gets passed to git config user.email",
            default=None)
        update_subparser.add_argument(
            "--credential-username",
            help="optional: push credential username",
            default=None)
        update_subparser.set_defaults(command=update)

        delete_subparser = subparsers.add_parser(
            "delete", description="Delete name and email stored for an alias")
        delete_subparser.add_argument(
            "alias", help="Delete name, email and possibly credentials for this alias")
        delete_subparser.add_argument(
            "--force", action="store_true", help="Delete without interaction"
        )
        delete_subparser.set_defaults(command=delete)

        show_subparser = subparsers.add_parser(
            "show",
            description="Show name and email associated with this alias")
        show_subparser.add_argument("alias", nargs="?", default=None)
        show_subparser.set_defaults(command=show)
    else:
        parser.add_argument(
            "alias",
            nargs="?",
            default=None,
            help="Use git config with name and email that belong to this alias")
        parser.add_argument(
            "--quiet", action="store_true",
            help="Suppress confirmation output after setting the config"
        )
        parser.add_argument(
            "--version", action="store_true",
            help="show git and git-user version and exit"
        )
        parser.set_defaults(command=switch)

    args = parser.parse_args()
    if getattr(args, "version", False):
        print("git-user version {}".format(__version__))
        return

    try:
        args.command(args)
    except (UserbaseError, CalledProcessError) as err:
        print(err)
        sys.exit(1)

    # only save on proper exit
    _USERS.save()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

To test it, copy and paste the file somewhere in your `$PATH` where git can pick it up, name it `git-user` and make it executable. A symlink with this name is also possible if you prefer to have the file with a `.py` extension.

#### Notes to kind reviewers

- Every kind of feedback is welcome. I'm also especially interested, how the script worked for you regarding usability. Was the help text actually, well, helpful?
- As one of the comments tells, I knowingly ignored possibly useful packages like `click` in order to allow this to run on systems with no additional python packages.
- Support for signature keys that would make it easier to sign your commits as well is on the TODO list, but not implemented yet.
- The code was checked with `pylint` and `pycodestyle`, so it should be in a reasonable shape regarding code style.

---

¹ Whether or not this is a good idea might be arguable, but that's not the point here.

Comment: I'm wondering why you didn't avoid the whole problem by adding the shared repository as a remote for the different developers, but I'm not gonna judge :D

Comment: @Vogel612 Yeah, that would be the most sensible choice. But unfortunately a few ideas/concepts from the SVN world are deeply stuck in the habits of some people ;-) And as of now, I have not been able to drive them off of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's great I'd say, nothing really to complain except the suggestion to
handle missing files more gracefully:

- Run the script, `/home/ferada/.config/git-user/users.json` gets created successfully.
- Delete that file.
- Run the script again, get a crash.

```
0 codementor % python3 git-user.py
Creating default at '/home/ferada/.config/git-user/users.json'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "git-user.py", line 134, in <module>
    _USERS = Userbase(_USERS_FILE)
  File "git-user.py", line 37, in __init__
    self._load()
  File "git-user.py", line 42, in _load
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(self._users_file))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 223, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/home/ferada/.config/git-user'
```

The `os.makedirs` call needs an `exist_ok=True` parameter, then that
gets handled.

---

Maybe the argument parser construction should really be separated from
the `main` function, it's a distinct functionality and could very well
be tested separately.

`_git_config_name` and `_git_config_email` could always to `strip` and
`decode`, that seems better than doing it on all but one call site
anyway.

The `--version` flag also has special handling in `argparse` which you
could use, c.f. `version=` for `add_argument`.

On that note, I don't like that `--help` doesn't give me a full list of
the subcommands because it's construction is split in two parts.  While
reading about that topic of default subparsers (which I thought is how
this might be handled) it looks like that is fraught with peril.

So, might I simply suggest that the possible subcommands are mentioned
in the top-level `--help` output?  Or you did already do that and
omitted it as said in the help text.  Well, at least you know your users
definitely will want that help information.

Comment: Thanks very much. Great find on that `os.makedirs` error! Re: your comment on the help text: the full help text is shown in the question. If what you are looking for is not in there, well, ... my fault I guess ;-) The "two stage help text" with `git user -h`, where the subcommands are shown (maybe I've missed some), and e.g. `git user add -h` is similar to how git handles this, see e.g. `git remote add -h`.